# PHP json_encode() get printed with <head> and <body> tags

Tags: php, json

When I echo out a json_encode the results are enclosed in `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>` tags. The file is saved as a .php file

Here is the code for the file (minus the database connection)

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

// connect to db...query etc...

$arr = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[] = $row;
}

echo '{"members":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

How do I only output the json as the info is going to be used in an iOS application?

Comment: The code you provide will not output any of those tags. Are you sure they appear in the actual data you are getting back and that you aren't using an application that displays JSON documents by converting them to HTML?

Comment: I did think that. I'm just viewing the source in chrome, I suppose thats adding the html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chrome inspector shows you what Chrome is doing to interpret and display the file (that is, formatting the data as a web page/html-file, and including extension behaviour), this is an example of a .json-file opened in Chrome (the script is inserted by an extension):
[image: Chrome opening JSON]

Viewing the source itself (`view-source:http://url.com/file.json`) should however display the raw data, which is what your application will see.

Comment: Ahhh good to know. I was doing inspect element, which obviously shows the html markup.